# Internal DNS conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, apache-kafka

I am running two servers on Aws and I have an external DNS configured for the servers.

When I try to connect to kafka port using the dns name from command line using telnet, it connects perfectly.

When I do the same with the Kafka consumer or producer, the private dns of the amazon gets resolved and as there is no connectivity between the internal dns, it does not work.

I am able to connect MySQL between these two servers.

Appreciate any help in this regards.

Thanks,

Ranjith

www.bevywise.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
[Kafka server configuration - listeners vs. advertised.listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998859/kafka-server-configuration-listeners-vs-advertised-listeners)

In short, setting 
advertised.listeners = yourdns:port should resolve the problem