# Kafka NodePort service is unreachable outside of cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

I have been trying to deploy Kafka using [Helm charts](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/cp-helm-charts/docs/index.html). So I defined NodePort service for Kafka pods. I checked console Kafka producer and consumer with the same hosts and ports - they work properly. However, when I create Spark application as data consumer and Kafka as producer they are not able to connect to the Kafka service0. I used minikube ip (instead of node ip) for the host and service NodePort port.
Although, in Spark logs, I saw that NodePort service resolves endpoints and brokers are discovered as pods addressed and ports:

```
INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] Discovered group coordinator 172.17.0.20:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] (Re-)joining group
WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] Connection to node 2147483645 (/172.17.0.20:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] Group coordinator 172.17.0.20:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] Connection to node 2 (/172.17.0.20:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=avro_data] Connection to node 0 (/172.17.0.12:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

How this behavior can be changed?

NodePort service definition looks like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: cp-kafka
    release: my-confluent-oss
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9092
      port: 32400
      nodePort: 32400
  type: NodePort
```

Spark consumer configuration:

```
def kafkaParams() = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "192.168.99.100:32400",
  "schema.registry.url" -> "http://192.168.99.100:8081",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "avro_data",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
```

Kafka producer configuration:

```
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.99.100:32400")
  props.put("client.id", "avro_data")
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
  props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://192.168.99.100:32500")
```

All the K8s services for Kafka:

```
NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
kafka-service                            NodePort       10.99.113.234    <none>        32400:32400/TCP     6m34s
kubernetes                               ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP             27d
my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka                ClusterIP      10.100.156.108   <none>        9092/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka-connect        ClusterIP      10.99.78.89      <none>        8083/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka-headless       ClusterIP      None             <none>        9092/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka-rest           ClusterIP      10.100.152.109   <none>        8082/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-ksql-server          ClusterIP      10.96.249.202    <none>        8088/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-schema-registry      ClusterIP      10.109.27.45     <none>        8081/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-zookeeper            ClusterIP      10.102.182.90    <none>        2181/TCP            102m
my-confluent-oss-cp-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>        2888/TCP,3888/TCP   102m
schema-registry-service                  NodePort       10.103.100.64    <none>        32500:32500/TCP     33m
zookeeper-np                             NodePort       10.98.180.130    <none>        32181:32181/TCP     53m
```

Comment: You need to [set KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) to the NodePort IP address so that clients can correctly connect to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access kafka broker outside k8 minikube cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757330/access-kafka-broker-outside-k8-minikube-cluster)

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/issues/192

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I was trying to access kafka broker ([cp-helm-chart](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts)) running on minikube from outside.

Here how I resolved it. Before you install using helm install from local repository.

1. Edit inside this file https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka/values.yaml
2. Search for nodeport: and change its enabled field to true.

   nodeport:
   enabled: true
3. Uncomment these two lines by removing #:
   "advertised.listeners": |-
   EXTERNAL://${HOST_IP}:$((31090 + ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID}))
4. Replace ${HOST_IP} by your minikube ip (enter minikube ip in cmd to retrieve your k8s host ip e.g : 196.169.99.100)
5. Replace ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID} by the broker id (if only one broker is running than its will be by default just 0)
6. Finally it would look something like this:
   "advertised.listeners": |-
   EXTERNAL://196.169.99.100:31090

Now you can access the kafka broker running within k8s cluster from outside by pointing the bootstrap.servers to 196.169.99.100:31090