# Is there a way to start a Zookeeper server using my static ip instead of localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've started learning some big data tools for a new project, and right now I'm on Kafka and Zookeeper.

I have them both install on my local machine, and I can start them up and start producing and consuming messages just fine. Now, I want to try it having two machines, one with a kafka broker, zookeepr and a producer, and the other with a consumer. Lets call them Machine A and Machine B.

Machine A has runs the Zookeeper server, the broker and a producer. Machine B runs a consumer. From what I think I understand, I should be able to setup the consumer to listen to a topic from the producer on Machine A, using Zookeeper. Since both machines are on the same network (i.e. my local home network), I thought I could change the kafka broker server.properties to use my static ip address for Machine A, and then have the consumer on Machine B connect to it.

My problem, is that zookeeper keeps spinning up on localhost, and connecting to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 so when my broker tries to connect to it using my static ip address (i.e 192.168.x.x), it times out. I have looked all over for a solution, but I cannot find anything that tells me how to configure the Zookeeper sever to start on a different ip address.

Maybe my understanding of these technologies is simply wrong, but I thought this would be a fairly simple thing to do. Does anyone know any way to resolve this? Or else if I'm doing it completely wrong, what is the correct approach

Comment: *consumer to listen to a topic from the producer on Machine A, using Zookeeper* -- Consumers should be setup to listen via Kafka, not Zookeeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> zookeeper keeps spinning up on localhost, and connecting to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181

Well, that is the *bind address*.

You need to also (preferably) have a static IP for Zookeeper, then set `zookeeper.connect` within the `server.properties` file of Kafka to reach to that other machine's external address.

From the Zookeeper configuration file, you would make sure you have the `myid` file and have a line in the property file that looks like this (without the double brackets)

```
server.{{ myid }}={{ ip_address }}:2888:3888
```

You wouldn't find this in the Kafka documentation, but it is in the [Zookeeper documentation](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.13/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_clusterOptions)

---

However, if Kafka and Zookeeper are on the same machine, this isn't necessary.

Your external consumer should be setting `bootstrap.servers` property and the Kafka IP address(es) w/ port 9092.

Your problem might me related instead to [the **`advertised.listeners`** setting within Kafka.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998859/kafka-server-configuration-listeners-vs-advertised-listeners)

For example, start with `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092`

Comment: So in my server.properties file I have `listeners=PLAINTEXT://myStaticIPAddress:9092` and the `zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181` and when I start the consumer on the other machine I do start it up pointing the `bootstrap.server` property to the other machines static ip address. But it will tell me that the brooker may be unavailable.. I've also checked the `server.properties` file and I don't have a `advertised.listeners` property anywhere in there. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Start by setting the listeners property to `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`, then make sure Kafka is actually running and then from the other machine, try Netcat or telnet commands to test the port connection

Comment: Ok so when I set the listeners property to `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`, I get an error starting kafka saying `Cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable address` By the looks of it is has to `localhost` or the static ip

Comment: You can also use `PLAINTEXT://:9092`

Comment: That has worked! Thank you so much! I guess just so I'm clear, does `PLAINTEXT://:9092` mean that the broker is listening for any connections from any server on that port? That part is still a bit unclear to me

Comment: I think so ;) I just copied that from our running brokers

Comment: Unfortunately, while this solution works on my home network, it does not work at my office. Once I start up the broker, it still tells me that the `broker may be unavailable`, and I cannot connect any consumers to it. Any final suggestions? It could be our internal network, but I'm not really sure

Comment: If it works in one network, but not another, I would think that's an external firewall problem

Answer (score 2):

As of [Zookeeper 3.3.0](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html) (see Advanced Configuration):

> clientPortAddress : New in 3.3.0: the address (ipv4, ipv6 or hostname)
>   to listen for client connections; that is, the address that clients
>   attempt to connect to. This is optional, by default we bind in such a
>   way that any connection to the clientPort for any
>   address/interface/nic on the server will be accepted

So you could use:

```
clientPortAddress=127.0.0.1
```