# Kafka Error connecting to node ubuntukafka:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: python, java, apache-kafka, virtualbox

I have two servers on VirtualBox guests each ubuntu.  I can SSH from my main machine to both, and between the two so they all have the natnetwork.

I ran on one server kafka as described here:

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

So I brought up singlenode zookeper
Kafka then started.  I added the test topic.
(All on MachineA . 10.75.1.247)

I am trying to list the topics on that node from another machine:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 10.75.1.247:9092
```

from MachineB (10.75.1.2)

doing that, causes the error over and over:

```
[2019-09-16 23:57:07,864] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node ubuntukafka:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntukafka
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:151)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:943)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:288)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:925)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1140)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

it does resolve the name
(says ubuntukafka instead of ubuntukafkanode) but fails.

What am I missing?  Am I using kafka wrong?  I thought I could have a nice kafka server where all my other servers with data can produce information too.  Then many other consumers can read the information from?

Ultimately what I wanted to test was if I could send messages to my kafka server:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.75.1.247:9092 --topic test
```

And even then use python later to produce messages to the server.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='10.75.1.247:9092')
for _ in range(100):
    try:
        producer.send('test', b'some_message_bytes')
    except:
        print('doh')
```

Comment: Please show your server properties files

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Generally, seems your hostnames aren't resolvable. Does `ping ubuntukafka` work? If not, then you'll need to adjust what you're making Kafka return via `advertised.listeners` to be the external IP rather than the hostname

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.75.1.247:9092
```

Where, `10.75.1.247` is the network address to be resolved by the external machines (e.g. make sure you can ping that address, too)

Comment: you are right it does not respond to the ubuntukafka, that is just the machine name.  It gets it somehow (its not in a hosts file anywhere unless ubuntu automatically did that) in either case, where does the advertised.listeners go in the kafka/config folder?  is PLAINTEXT in the above example just 10.75.1.247 or the ip address of machine A?  and the advertised.listeners is on machine A?

Comment: PLAINTEXT is a protocol. Both lines already exist as part of `server.properties`, they just need to be adjusted and uncommented. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998859/kafka-server-configuration-listeners-vs-advertised-listeners

Comment: Each Kafka server requires its own unique advertised listener for clients to connect to. It could be a hostname, but it appears your DNS or hosts file isn't setup, so just use IPs

Comment: I got it working just great with this info using their .sh files to test with.  Still no go on the python but that is another issue/topic to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

only changing listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 work for me no need to change advertised.listeners property in server config

Comment: This setup would only work on a local machine, though

Answer (score 0):

You can add below into file /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 ${your/hostname}
```

Comment: This already exists in any Ubuntu server and should never be done to fix Kafka issues