# expose kafka broker to interal and external IP

Tags: apache-kafka, listener, broker

I have a Kafka cluster on 3 vms each vm has a Kafka and zookeeper service.
I tried to configure listener for broker as you can see below:
but after restart I get the below errors can you tell me why each log is  different and how can I solve this

**one vm log has this error:**

```
[2021-01-10 17:05:18,051] WARN [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (/172.29.141.57:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-01-10 17:05:18,107] WARN [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=2] Connection to node 2 (/172.29.141.135:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

**another vm has this error:**

```
[2021-01-10 17:05:33,579] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2021-01-10 17:05:38,579] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

**/opt/kafka/config/server.properties -**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=1

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.2.4.18:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.29.141.96:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/data/kafka

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.minutes=20

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=10.20.4.180:2181,10.20.4.181:2181,10.20.4.207:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
delete.topic.enable=true
message.max.bytes=104857600
```

Comment: See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: I suggest you look into using Ansible or similar tool to create a cluster

Comment: broker.id should start from 0. 0 for broker 1, 1 for broker 2, 2 for broker 3. Try setting these.

Comment: Can you share server.properties for all brokers?

Answer (score -1):

In your server.properties file, you configured advertised.listeners with only on broker ip-host:port. Can you change it and specify a comma-separated list of all your brokers?
e.g.: `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-broker1:port1,PLAINTEXT://ip-broker2:port2,PLAINTEXT://ip-broker3:port3`

Comment: and give each listener a different port? its an example of one config for each broker I secify only its own IP in advertised.listeners section

Comment: Each broker must only advertise itself. The client bootstrap protocol collects all addresses

Comment: @OneCricketeer You're false. See the Kafka documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) or this thread in StackOverflow :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998859/kafka-server-configuration-listeners-vs-advertised-listeners . Thnaks to remove your negative vote to my answer.

Comment: @Noap You give the port configured for each broker, this can be the same, it depends on your configuration. If you specify only one and corresponding broker is unavailable for whatever reason, this can be an issue.

Comment: I'm quite aware of the documentation. You can't advertise other machines addresses from one server. You _can_ advertise _multiple network interfaces_ of the **same** machine, which is not what this answer is doing