# Accessing kafka container in Buildkite pipeline

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, testcontainers, buildkite

I have the following setup (simplified version) using Test Containers for my integration tests:

```
public class IntegrationTestFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private static readonly string NetworkName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private readonly INetwork _network = new NetworkBuilder()
        .WithName(NetworkName)
        .Build();

    private readonly PostgreSqlContainer _postgreSqlContainer = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
        .WithImage("postgres:14.7")
        .WithName("psql")
        .WithHostname("psql")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(5432))
        .WithPortBinding(5432, 5432)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "POSTGRES_DB", “test-db” },
                { "POSTGRES_USER", "test-db-user“ },
                { "POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "test-db-password“ }
            }))
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .Build();

    private readonly IContainer _zookeeperContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0")
        .WithHostname("zookeeper")
        .WithName("zookeeper")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT", "2181" },
                { "ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME", "2000" }
            }))
        .WithPortBinding(2181, 2181)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(2181))
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .Build();

    private readonly IContainer _kafkaContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0")
        .WithHostname("broker")
        .WithName("broker")
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "KAFKA_BROKER_ID", "1" },
                { "KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT", "zookeeper:2181" },
                { "KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP", "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT" },
                { "KAFKA_LISTENERS", "PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092" },
                { "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS", "PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092" },
                { "KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR", "1" },
                { "KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS", "0" },
                { "KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR", "1" },
                { "KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR", "1" },
                { "KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "true" }
           }))
        .WithPortBinding(9092, 9092)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(9092))
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .Build();

    private readonly IContainer _schemaRegistryContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0")
        .WithHostname("schema-registry")
        .WithName("schema-registry")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry" },
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "broker:29092" },
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081" }
            }))
        .WithPortBinding(8081, 8081)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(8081))
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .Build();

    private readonly IContainer _restProxyContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.0")
        .WithHostname("rest-proxy")
        .WithName("rest-proxy")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME", "rest-proxy" },
                { "KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "broker:29092" },
                { "KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8082" },
                { "KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL", "http://schema-registry:8081" }
            }))
        .WithPortBinding(8082, 8082)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(8082))
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .Build();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            var isBuildkite = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILDKITE") == "true";
            var host = isBuildkite ? "172.17.0.1" : "localhost";
        
            // Replace DbContext
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
            services.RemoveDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var appConnectionString =
             $"Host={host};Port=5432;Database=test-db;Username=test-db-user;Password=test-db-password;”;
        
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(appConnectionString, sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                sqlOptions.UseNodaTime();
            }));
        
            // Override Kafka config
            services.AddKafkaProducer(new ConfigurationBuilder().Build(), options =>
            {
                options.TopicName = "MyTopicName";
                options.RetryCount = 1;
                options.RetryTimeoutInSeconds = 1;
                options.BootstrapServers = $"{host}:9092";
                options.SchemaRegistry = $"http://{host}:8081";
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I can run my integration tests on my local machine with the host value `localhost`. When I try to run these tests on Buildkite pipeline, I confirm that I can connect to PostgreSql instance by using the host `172.17.0.1` but can not access to Kafka broker. I tried multiple host values as the `BootstrapServers` like `172.17.0.1:9092`, `172.17.0.1:29092`, `broker:9092`, `broker: 29092`, `localhost:9092`, `localhost:29092` but no luck.
When I try to run it with `172.17.0.1:9092`, I get the following error:

> localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection
> refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)

What should be my `BootstrapServers` value to access to my Kafka container in Buildkite pipeline?

Comment: maybe at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71294274/7241367  post solve you problem

Comment: 1) I suggest you use latest Confluent images. 2) If you only want Kafka, it no longer requires Zookeeper, and you don't need other things like Registry or REST Proxy. 3) To fix the error, "advertise" that IP, not localhost as the listener. Bootstrapping is only the initial connection, not what Kafka clients will actually use. Also, ideally you never hard code IP addresses. Can you not get that elsewhere from the environment or a config?